# isBetween using moment-timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am attempting to use moment-timezone to do some calculations based on an hour.

```
var time = moment.tz() // get the now
var start = moment.tz('16:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss', '');
var end = moment.tz('16:10:00', 'HH:mm:ss', '');

if(time.isBetween(start, end)) {
  console.log('yep')
}
```

but the output is always `undefined`.

I have tried countless ways to get this to work but to no avail.

```
moment.tz(moment.now(), 'Europe/Lisbon').isBetween('16:00:00','17:30:00') // to get in ms
```

false

```
moment.tz('Europe/Lisbon').isBetween('16:00:00','17:30:00')
```

false

```
moment.tz(moment.tz('Europe/Lisbon').format('HH:mm:ss'), 'Europe/Lisbon').isBetween('16:00:00','17:30:00')
```

What could I be doing wrong?
I am using time-zone because I need the actual hour of many different places.

thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) docs states:

> The `moment.tz` constructor takes all the same arguments as the moment constructor, but uses the last argument as a [time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

So you have to pass a valid timezone identified (e.g. `'Europe/Lisbon'`) instead of `''`.

`'16:00:00'` and `'17:30:00'` in your [`isBetween`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) will represent **local** `'16:00:00'` for today, as [Default](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/defaults/) section states. Use `moment.tz(String, String, String);` instead to parse using zone.

Here a snippet showing how you can get if current time is between a given range in zone:

```js
function update() {
  var tmz = $("#tmz").val();
  var fmt = 'HH:mm:ss';
  
  var time = moment.tz(tmz);
  var start = moment.tz('16:00:00', fmt, tmz);
  var end = moment.tz('17:30:00', fmt, tmz);
  
  $(".time").text(time.format(fmt));
  $("#zone").text(tmz);
  if(time.isBetween(start, end)) {
    console.log('yep');
    $("#bool").text("IS");
  } else {
    $("#bool").text("IS NOT");
  }
}

$("#tmz").on("change", update);
update();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>

<select id="tmz">
  <option value="America/Los_Angeles">America/Los_Angeles</option>
  <option value="America/New_York">America/New_York</option>
  <option value="Europe/London">Europe/London</option>
  <option value="Europe/Rome">Europe/Rome</option>
  <option value="Asia/Tehran">Asia/Tehran</option>
  <option value="Asia/Kolkata">Asia/Kolkata</option>
  <option value="Australia/Sydney">Australia/Sydney</option>
</select>

<br/>
Now is <span class="time"></span> in <span id="zone"></span><br/>
<span class="time"></span> <span id="bool"></span> between 16:00:00 and 17:30:00
```

Comment: I feel dumb... I tried so many ways and now I understand what I was doing wrong...

Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome, no need to feel dumb! I'm glad my answer helped :)

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @VincenzoC I was able to figure it out so for future refs or for people trying to find the simplest solution here is the code I used to test this. Again thanks @VincenzoC.

**code:**

```
var tmz = 'Europe/Lisbon';
var fmt = 'HH:mm:ss';
var time = moment.tz(tmz);
var start = moment.tz('12:00:00', fmt, tmz);
var end = moment.tz('15:00:00', fmt, tmz);

if(time.isBetween(start, end)) {
    console.log('Yes it is')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve this in my project. It has validation for the input dates as well.

**Code:**

```js
const isDateInRange = ({
  format = 'HH:mm:ss',
  timeZone = 'Europe/Lisbon',
  start,
  end
} = {}) => {
  const dateStart = moment.tz(start, format, timeZone);
  const dateEnd = moment.tz(end, format, timeZone);

  if (!dateStart.isValid() || !dateEnd.isValid()) {
    return false;
  }

  return moment().isBetween(dateStart, dateEnd);
};

if (isDateInRange({ start: '10:00:00', end: '12:00:00' })) {
  console.log('Yep');
} else {
  console.log('Nope');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript function covering edge-cases of different timezones being a day ahead or behind:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

interface CurrentTimeIsBetweenTzTimeProps {
  currentTime?: any;
  tmz?: string;
  startTime?: string;
  endTime?: string;
  fmt?: string;
}
export const currentTimeIsBetweenTzTime = ({
  currentTime = new Date(),
  tmz = 'America/New_York',
  startTime = '09:00:00',
  endTime = '18:00:00',
  fmt = 'HH:mm:ss',
}: CurrentTimeIsBetweenTzTimeProps = {}) => {
  const time = moment.tz(currentTime, tmz);
  const start = moment.tz(startTime, fmt, tmz);
  const end = moment.tz(endTime, fmt, tmz);
  return time.isBetween(start, end)
    || time.isBetween(start.subtract(1, 'day'), end.subtract(1, 'day'))
    || time.isBetween(start.add(2, 'day'), end.add(2, 'day'));
}
```

Tests passing:

```
describe('currentTimeIsBetweenTzTime', () => {
  // Date Fri Oct 23 2020 15:06:40 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
  const timestamp = new Date(1603480000000)
  it('it is between start and end', () => {
    expect(currentTimeIsBetweenTzTime({
      currentTime: timestamp,
      tmz: 'America/New_York',
      startTime: '15:00:00',
      endTime: '15:30:00',
    })).toBe(true);
    expect(currentTimeIsBetweenTzTime({
      currentTime: timestamp,
      tmz: 'America/Chicago',
      startTime: '14:00:00',
      endTime: '14:30:00',
    })).toBe(true);
    expect(currentTimeIsBetweenTzTime({
      currentTime: timestamp,
      tmz: 'Australia/Sydney',
      startTime: '06:00:00',
      endTime: '06:30:00',
    })).toBe(true);
  });
  it('it is not between start and end', () => {
    expect(currentTimeIsBetweenTzTime({
      currentTime: timestamp,
      tmz: 'America/Chicago',
      startTime: '15:00:00',
      endTime: '15:30:00',
    })).toBe(false);
    expect(currentTimeIsBetweenTzTime({
      currentTime: timestamp,
      tmz: 'America/New_York',
      startTime: '14:00:00',
      endTime: '14:30:00',
    })).toBe(false);
    expect(currentTimeIsBetweenTzTime({
      currentTime: timestamp,
      tmz: 'Australia/Sydney',
      startTime: '06:15:00',
      endTime: '06:30:00',
    })).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Or with `dayjs`:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat';
import dayjsIsBetween from 'dayjs/plugin/isBetween';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);
dayjs.extend(dayjsIsBetween);
dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);

interface CurrentTimeIsBetweenTzTimeProps {
  currentTime?: any;
  tmz?: string;
  startTime?: string;
  endTime?: string;
  fmt?: string;
}
export const currentTimeIsBetweenTzTime = ({
  currentTime = new Date().valueOf(),
  tmz = 'America/New_York',
  startTime = '09:00:00',
  endTime = '18:00:00',
  fmt = 'HH:mm:ss',
}: CurrentTimeIsBetweenTzTimeProps = {}) => {
  const time = dayjs.tz(currentTime, tmz);
  const start = dayjs.tz(startTime, fmt, tmz);
  const end = dayjs.tz(endTime, fmt, tmz);
  return (
    time.isBetween(start, end) || time.isBetween(start.subtract(1, 'day'), end.subtract(1, 'day')) || time.isBetween(start.add(1, 'day'), end.add(1, 'day'))
  );
};
```